How to make rept formula work in google sheets?
Can't understand why the REPT function doesn't work for me at all.
It says "Formula parse error".
Here's the simple formulat I'm trying to use:
=REPT("Hello", 3)

It still doesn't work. I have no idea why.
Googling didn't help either.

I tried googling but found no solution unfortunately

upd. it doesn't work in a spreadsheet I need it to wor in. but in a new empty one it works, does anybody know why is can be like that?

Try: =rept("Hello";3) (comma vs semicolon convention based on sheet locale)

It might be possible that your spreadsheet is set to use ; instead of , as a function parameters separator. Change your formula...
From
=REPT("hello", 3)

To
=REPT("hello"; 3)

